# How can I implement a 1st person camera view?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, button, camera

I'm following this tutorial right now: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-camera?playlist=17141

I've managed to implement a 3rd person camera view button, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the same for a 1st person camera view. Below is a camera control script that I attached to the main camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset;
    public bool thirdPerson;
    public bool firstPerson;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // 3rd person camera view
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 50, 140, 40), "3rd Person Camera"))
        {
            thirdPerson = true;
        }

        // 1st person camera view
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 110, 140, 40), "1st Person Camera"))
        {
            firstPerson = false;
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (thirdPerson == true)
        {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single camera and change its position based on which viewing angle should be active. Try to attatch **two empty objects** as **children** to your player object and add a reference to them in your script (your camera also needs to be a child of your player for this to work). Then drag & drop them from the hierarchy to the inspector and just **switch between those positions** like so:

```
public Transform firstPersonPosition;
public Transform thirdPersonPosition;
public Camera camera;

private void GoFirstPerson()
{
    camera.transform.position = firstPersonPosition.position;
}
private void GoThirdPerson()
{
    camera.transform.position = thirdPersonPosition.position;
}
```

You can basically use them as "waypoints" for your camera to jump to.

//Edit: 
If you are having problems with understanding how your code affects your GameObjects during Play Mode just switch to **Scene View** during play and look at your objects and where they are in the scene. I bet your first person camera is somewhere in your player model because you set its position to your players position.

Answer (score 2):

Well, while it might be okay for such a small tutorial: 
you should not use the GUI and OnGUI stuff for ingame UI. unity released in version 4.6 (years ago) a better UI system.

you could have 2 cameras, one for 3rd person one for 1st person. when pressing one of your buttons, you disable one camera and enable the other.

---

based on your edit:

you currently have 2 bool variables there, one for "firstPerson" one for "thirdPerson", thats redundant.

what do you do if both are true? or both are false? just have one variable e.g. "thirdPerson" true -> use 3rd person, false -> use 1st person.

also i see that you have decided to change the cameras position instead of using 2 cameras. this is also is a possible way to accomplish your goal

Comment: Thanks, I made some progress so I'll go ahead and update my question above!

Comment: i've edited my answer a bit, which might lead you in the right direction

Comment: Ah ok, good to know. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to set the position for 1st camera view though; I thought that setting "transform.position" to the "player.transform.position" would do the trick, but I seem to be too zoomed in on something (all I see is a blue blob). Any suggestions?